# WP Query merge with get_post_meta conditions

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a sidebar widget that will only appear on my custom post type `exhibitors` single template.

This widget simply gets Custom Field Meta data from the`exhibitors` and outputs it in a list format.

Each Custom Field post_meta field has a different purpose and is formatted slightly different. Some are just text and some are hyperlinks.

**MY PROBLEM**

I some how need my WP Query only to run if any of my 6 post_meta's exist.

If none exist, then I don't need any of the list surroundings to appear.

You will see what I tried below but fails miserably.

```
<?php 

    $currentID      = get_the_ID();
    $exhibitorMeta      = new WP_Query(array(

      'post_type'       => 'exhibitors',
      'post_id'         => $currentID

)); ?>

<?php if ($exhibitorMeta->have_posts()) : ?> 

    <?php while ($exhibitorMeta->have_posts()) : $exhibitorMeta->the_post(); ?>


        <?php if (  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Facebook Page', true) ||
                    get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Twitter User', true) ||
                    get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Web Address', true) ||
                    get_post_meta($post->ID, 'E-mail Address', true) ||
                    get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Stand Number', true) ||
                    get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Hall Number', true)
        ) { ?>

        <div class="module sidebar">

            <div class="module-head">

                Exhibitor Info

            </div>

            <div class="module-body">

                <ul class="sidebar-list">

                    <?php if (  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Facebook Page', true) ) echo '

                        <li><a href="' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Facebook Page', true) . '">View our Facebook Page</a></li>

                    '; ?>

                    <?php if (  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Twitter User', true) ) echo '

                        <li><a href="' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Twitter User', true) . '">Follow us on Twitter</a></li>

                    '; ?>

                    <?php if (  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Web Address', true) ) echo '

                        <li><a href="' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Web Address', true) . '">View Website</a></li>

                    '; ?>

                    <?php if (  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'E-mail Address', true) )

                    $emailAddress = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'E-mail Address', true);

                    echo '

                        <li><a href="mailto:' . $emailAddress . '" title="' . $emailAddress . '" target="_blank">' . $emailAddress . '</a></li>

                    '; ?>

                    <?php if (  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Stand Number', true) ) echo '

                        <li>Stand Number: ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Stand Number', true) . '</li>

                    '; ?>

                    <?php if (  get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Hall Number', true) ) echo '

                        <li>Hall Number: ' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Hall Number', true) . '</li>

                    '; ?>

                </ul>

            </div>

            <div class="module-foot"></div>

        </div>

        <?php } ?>


    <?php endwhile; ?> 

<?php unset($exhibitorMeta); endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

You can see I have tried to use PHP `||` comparison within the WP Query to only show the list surroundings if any of my 6 meta values exist. But for some reason, it just outputs the  list surroundings 6 times.

So it's all wrong.

**MY QUESTION**

Is it posible, using the same WP Query information, to retrieve the post_meta data information, but if no post_meta's exist, then the list surroundings don't appear.

But if one or more post_meta's exist, then the list surroundings appear with the active post_meta's appearing in their formated way.

Any would be so great because I can't seem to find much on using multiple post_meta values like this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want the if statement to check if the custom value exists, not if the get_post_meta returned something.

Try this:

```
    <?php 
    $values = get_post_custom_values("Facebook Page"); 
    if ($values[0]) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo $values[0]; ?>">View our Facebook Page</a></li>
    <?php 
    } else { 
        // 
    } 
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @anuragbh - but I'm intrigued how I would get this to work with and array of custom fields. So for example if none of my 6 custom fields existed, then how do I stop my `<ul>` and parent `<div>`'s from showing?

I managed to find a fix using this method, but I guess it is a little bulky... https://gist.github.com/3049707

Comment: Your solution is what I had in mind using a lot of if statements too. True it is bulky and it seems there should be a better way. To hide the div and ul tags if none of the values exist, you could: Initialize a bool variable to false, change it to true if any of the custom fields do have a value (your existing if statements). If the variable is true, show the div, ul and the rest of the tags, or just switch display none on/off for the elements. Still not as efficient as I would like, but I will let you know if I find a better solution.